# Ember App - Initial State

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, ember.js

I'm learning Ember, and I've come across a situation where I haven't been able to find a pattern online.

My application's main route includes a list of "stories" (think scrum).  However, this list also has a `StoryController` associated with it.  I don't want to assign the stories in the `IndexRoute` file; it doesn't feel like it belongs there.  I ended up adding a property to the `StoriesController` and calling the `App.Story.fetch()` method to the Controller's `init()` method.  I can't help but feel there is a better, more "Ember" way to do this.

**App.IndexRoute**

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    renderTemplate: function(){
        this.render();

        this.render('stories'); 
    }
});
```

**App.StoriesController**

```
App.StoriesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    init : function(){
        this.stories = App.Story.find();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can pass in the controller to the "stories" render function and use the model hook :

**App.IndexRoute**

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function(){
        this.render();
        this.render('stories', {controller: App.StoriesController}); 
    }
});
```

**App.StoriesController**

```
App.StoriesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    model : function() {
        return App.Story.find();
    }
});
```